# Set SVG as mouse pointer image

Tags: jquery, svg, mouseover, mouse-cursor

I am having a svg image .I neet to set that svg image as mouse pointer using javascript.

I can able to set the image as mouse pointer using following code:

```
  $("div").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).attr("style","cursor: url(red_bucket.png), pointer;");
        });
```

Is there any possiblities to set the svg as mouse pointer...?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
    $("div").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).attr("style","cursor: url('red_bucket.svg'), pointer;");
    });
```

Comment: Does the SVG file have to be a special kind of SVG?